# How to use Picasso in an Adapter without using context in Fragment

Tags: android, firebase, adapter, android-context, android-listfragment

When I try to use context in my **fragment** I get the error:

> constructor Adapter in class Adapter cannot be applied to given types;
>   required:Context,List<ListItem>,OnItemClickListener

I have declared my context in my adapter as follows:

```
 private Context mContext;
```

then i initialized the context:

```
 public MyAdapter(Context context,List<ListItem> listItems, OnItemClickListener callback) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
    this.callback = callback;
    this.mContext = context;

}
```

And used **mContext** to get my imageurl in the onBindViewHolder using picasso

```
 @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            ListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);

     Picasso.with(mContext).load(listItem.getImageurl()).into(holder.imageUrl;

        }
```

But now I can't seem to get around using this context in my Fragment.

This is what I've tried: In my **Fragment**:

**//an error occurs**

```
 adapter = new MyAdapter(this,listItems);
```

*so I tried this:*

**//still get an error**

```
  adapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(),this);
```

I also tried getActivity but still get an error

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity());
```

where am I going wrong?
All I am really trying to do is display the image in my listfragment but I don't know how to use Picasso with using context, and MyAdapter does not require context to function properly. I've been using it without declaring context and the data displays properly. Onclick is also working and displaying strings from firebase, but now I need to display images from Firebase using Picasso into my listfragment. Everything else works fine except this line of code in my Fragment:

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try Get context from any View object in `Holder`.
Example:

```
mContext = holder.imageView.getContext()
```

Comment: will definitely do so.Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Fragments are inflated inside an Activity.

1. In Fragment, you either use the context of the Activity or the context of the whole application.
2. Plus you have missed passing one more parameter in the Adapter, ie your click listener.

Define the adapter like this -

```
OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener = OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position) {

    }
}

adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), listItems, mOnItemClickListener);
```

or

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), listItems, mOnItemClickListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your adapter initialization you pass 2 parameters, but your constructor requires 3 parameters.

so try to initialize using 3 params:

```
   adapter=new MyAdapter(getContext(), listItems, this);
```

getContext()= context of fragment.

lisItems= your list.

this=is your click interface listener (make sure you implemented the listener in your fragment).

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I think you forgot last argument

```
OnItemClickListener listener = OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position) {
        //some code
    }
}
adapter = new MyAdapter(this, listItems, listener);
```